# inserting ini File into word with formatting

Tags: vba, insert, ms-word

I have  small bit of VBA code which works and inserts a File into a specific bookmark within word, but I'm struggling to format the Text from the file that gets inserted, either to use the format of the bookmark or to use specify the format on insert.

working code

```
    File_purchase_inv_def = HarvDir + "\v1live" + "\Purchase_Invoices.def"

    Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def) 
        oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BK_Puchase_Invioces").Range
        oRng.Select
        Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def)
```

The format i'm trying to use is "Verdana" and Font size "7" I have tried formatting the area of the bookmark and also the below code.

**Not working Example1**

```
    File_purchase_inv_def = HarvDir + "\v1live" + "\Purchase_Invoices.def"

    Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def) 
        oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BK_Puchase_Invioces").Range
        oRng.Select
        Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def)
           With .Styles(Normal).Font
                .Name = "Verdana"
                .Size = 7
                  End with
```

**Not working example 2**

```
File_purchase_inv_def = HarvDir + "\v1live" + "\Purchase_Invoices.def"

    Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def) 
        oRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BK_Puchase_Invioces").Range
        oRng.Select
        Selection.Range.InsertFile FileName:=(File_purchase_inv_def)
          Selection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
          Selection.Font.Size = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

This will use the formatting of the bookmark and replace whatever text the bookmark has:

```
Dim fPath
fPath = "C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\test.txt"

ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("BK_Puchase_Invioces").Range.Text = _
   CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile(fPath).ReadAll()
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the quick reply,  I have just tried you code but I get an invalid Procedure call

Answer (score 0):

sorry I missed the fpath variable in your code,  I have just tested it and it works fine, many thanks.